# Can you mark/tag a git commit as formatting only?

Tags: git

Essentially, I'd like to tag a commit as only formatting, so any conflicts should be solved with a theirs strategy.

Comment: What? not clear what you want?

Comment: You just want to mark commit in some way?

Comment: I assume you want an automatic way as you could just mark the tag itself with a special "code" like FORMAT_ONLY to the end of the tag.

Comment: @ArchiFloyd yes. So that when rebasing, or merging it'd just ignore that file automatically. I don't think that there is a way to do it, though something might be able to be hacked with rerere.

Comment: I'd think the thing to do is have a formatting-only _branch_ and merge other work into it.

Comment: Very manual after-the-fact solution but perhaps worth mentioning [`git blame --ignore-rev`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt---ignore-revltrevgt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: **no**, you can't.

While you could set up a merge rule [for certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5465122/520162), you cannot do this for a certain commit.