# Is it possible to merge in Git without being on the merged-to branch?

Tags: git, merge

Today I was using Git and something happened to me which I didn't know how to deal with.

I was on branch `development`, and I did `git fetch` to get the new `origin/master`. I wanted to merge `origin/master` into `master`, and end up with the updated `master` checked out. Normally, I would do this:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

But there was a problem; the currently checked-out branch `development` had a `.gitignore` which included a lot of files that the old `master` didn't. The old `master` had these files version-controlled. So Git wouldn't let me checkout `master`, because then these files would be overwritten.

I didn't know what to do, so I simply checked out `origin/master` instead.

If there was a way to merge `origin/master` into `master` without checking out `master`, I think that would have saved me. (And it was a fast-forward merge, so Merge-Fail wasn't an option.)

What can I do about this?

Comment: I didn't know .gitignore did that... do you have uncommitted changes on your development branch?

Comment: No. [This method was artificially made longer because of Stackoverflow's weird comment rules.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fully-fledged merge requires work tree to resolve conflicts.

If you know that merge is fast-forward, you can use `git update-ref`

Example:

```
git update-ref -m "Fast-forward merge" refs/heads/master refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Don't do just `git update-ref master`, as it will create "master" in `.git/` instead of `.git/refs/heads/` (`refs/remotes/origin/master` can be abbreviated to `origin/master`)

Comment: @Vi: Not a practical solution, I'd have to maintain that script/alias over many different servers.

Comment: @cool-RR, Why? Provided you access servers based on pubkeys (not typing passwords every time), it is just `for i in server1 server2 server3; do scp gitffmaster ${i}:/usr/local/bin/; done`

Comment: @Vi: Does that work in shared servers as well, where I don't have root access?

Comment: @cool-RR, If no root access then (provided you already have usable `$HOME/bin` directory) it is like `for i in server1 server2 server3; do scp gitffmaster ${i}:bin/; done`. In my system `.profile` automatically adds `$HOME/bin` to PATH if found. Also you can distribute `.gitconfig` file with alias for this command.

Comment: Is there a way to know for sure that a merge is fast-forward?

Comment: @AeroCross, You can check for fast-forwardness before that: `git merge-base refs/heads/master refs/remotes/origin/master` should be equal to the value of "refs/remotes/origin/master".

Answer (score 1):

I usually delete all the newly ignored files from the working tree in that case, so the `checkout` won't be overwriting them any more.  `git clean` can help you with that.  You might also look at the `-f` or `-m` options of `checkout` for other ways to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't work in this case-- These files were important and I wanted to save them. I can transfer them to a temporary folder, but that would be cumbersome.

Comment: @cool-RR, you want to save them, but not version them, and you have changed them from the version in `master`?  It might be safer using a workflow like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp)