# Git: configure patterns for difftool and mergetool

Tags: git, mercurial, difftool, mergetool

In Mercurial, one can define a pattern for external diff and merge tools (so that they are called only for files matching the pattern specified):

```
[diff-patterns]
**.ext = difftool
[merge-patterns]
**.ext = mergetool
```

How to define such patterns in Git?

[mergetool] section in git-config(1) does not mention any pattern, mask or anyting similar.

**EDIT**:

Here is a relevant part of my .git/config:

```
[diff]
    tool = difftool
[difftool "difftool"]
    cmd = difftool.git.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE"

[merge]
    tool = mergetool
[mergetool "mergetool"]
    cmd = mergetool.git.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
```

Now it works for all files.

I want my difftool and mergetool to be called **only** for files with names ending with `.ext`

**EDIT**:

I have added a file .git/info/attributes with the following contents:

```
*.ext   diff=difftool
*.ext   merge=mergetool
```

I've also added

```
[diff "difftool"]
    name = my custom diff driver
    driver = difftool.git.sh %A %B %O
[merge "mergetool"]
    name = my custom merge driver
    driver = mergetool.git.sh %A %B %O %A
```

to my .git/config.

Now I run

```
git difftool
```

It calls KDiff3 instead of my difftool. What do I do wrong?

Remark: *I'm playing with difftool instead of mergetool because it is easier to test and I believe that if I manage to configure difftool, it will be obvious for me how to configure mergetool.*

**EDIT**:

Difftool now works.

.git/config:

```
[diff "difftool"]
    command = difftool.git.sh
```

.git/info/attributes:

```
.ext diff=difftool
```

difftool.git.sh (in PATH)

```
#!/bin/sh
difftool.jar "$2" "$5"
```

But there is a side-effect on Windows: `git diff` now results in APPCRASH.

**EDIT**:

I have figured out how to avoid crashing or hanging of `git diff`: one should use `git difftool` or call `git diff` through `sh`: `sh -c "git diff"`

Comment: Hi, can you update the answer with the **full** resolution? a lot of *edits* here to keep up what is the actual resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use a merge driver in a [`gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

See for instance "[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp)"

```
*.ext merge=mymergetool
```

You can use patterns in a gitattributes file.

Comment: Does the same apply to diff driver? Could not manage to make it work. I really need a simple sample.