# Apply merge rules from .gitattributes file to git rebase calls

Tags: git, rebase, git-merge, gitattributes

I have previously read and applied the instructions from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s) about setting up merge strategies for specific file types in git.  This works superbly for merges.  However, when I do a `git rebase`, the merge strategy isn't applied.

Is it possible to set `git rebase` up so that it applies a similar merge strategy to resolve certain conflicts automatically?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force rebase to apply the same rules for renamed files (cause problems too) as with a merge

```
 git rebase --merge
```

It might also work for your problem. It does not work when you want to apply eol conversion while rebasing.