# Git ignore file locally and always merge theirs

Tags: git, gitignore

I've got a git problem, the answer should be somewhere here on stackoverflow but I can't find it.

Imagine a team working on some project with sass or some other builded files. Multiple developers build the files and we want the builded files to be versioned in case a non-developer want to clone and check out the project without the need to build first.

But including the builded file in the project creates merge conflicts all the time.

We could ignore local changes and let only the lead developer check in his version time to time.

Ignoring could be done with a user defined .gitignore file or with:

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged path-to-file.css
```

But this creates a problem when pulling.

```
$ git pull

remote: Counting objects: 30, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 11), reused 16 (delta 11)
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done.
From github.com:User/MyProject
   4e1s389..a231344  development -> origin/master
Updating 63sdf04..a231344
error: Your local changes to 'path-to-file.css' would be overwritten by merge.  
Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

A workaround would be checking out the file all the time, for example with an alias:

```
git config --global alias.cobuilded 'checkout path-to-file.css'
```

And then after some work and building:

```
git cobuilded
git commit -am "work done"
git pull
git push
```

But there should be some kind of easier solution for this problem right?

```
git ignore-this-file-and-always-merge-theirs-from-origin path-to-file.css
```

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s) question and a possible solution to always merge theirs. But in my case the pull before the merge already fails...

Comment: How about changing strategy to not commit the css files at all on your master branch? You could still maintain your ideal of being able to clone a fully working repo, including css, by having your lead developer, an automated build server tool, or a post-commit-hook compile the scss->css on a separate branch. This separate branch would never be merged back to master, but would constantly have your master branch merged in to it, sass run against it, then the resulting css committed.

Comment: That sounds good. And when some end-user or tester needs a full working copy they can clone that repo instead of the master! Would it be possible to do this server side with some kind of push-hook ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's a good philosophy to follow:
**Don't check in generated files.**

Instead, provide a release area or - more generally speaking - a release mechanism to satisfy your customers (aka consuming teams).

Generally speaking, you're looking for a deployment system, not a version control system. You can combine the two, though. git is not a deployment system. Although admittedly it can go a long way, there are a few extensions to that direction, and I myself sometimes knowingly misuse it for that purpose out of convenience.

One approach is to use an automated build system that is triggered everytime a commit (or push) happens on a certain branch. There are open source tools for "continuous integration" tools available. Git provides hooks to trigger actions on e.g. pushes into a repo: `$GIT_DIR/hooks/post-receive`. Here's an excellent [example for sending emails](https://github.com/stephenh/git-central/blob/master/server/post-receive-email) automatically which can be modified to [export a release to a filesystem area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34201785/923794). Afterwards you can trigger the build process in that area.

Alternatively you could modify your existing build process to include a final build target. This one would export a copy of the build directory to the release area. The target should be manually triggered and only if tests pass.

Your project could contain a version controlled file, called the "bill of materials" (e.g. "release.bom") which lists all the files (with relative paths) that shall be copied to a release area when a release happens. That way you avoid to accidentally clutter the release area with those object or temporary files that no one has interest in.

If it's just for internal use by other teams, maybe a simple [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/), optionally with an `--exclude-from=FILE` option and a exclusion config file under git control is sufficient. Search for "rsync filter rules" to get more information about its syntax.