# jgit to detect conflicts before merge and apply merge strategy

Tags: git, merge, fetch, conflict, jgit

I am currently using [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) to merge remote branches, so after fetching from remote I would like to verify conflicts before I attempt to merge, so that I can decide what kind of merge strategy to use, for eg:

```
Myrepo/filesmodifiedbyme/file1.txt
Myrepo/filesmodifiedbysomeone/file2.txt
```

After fetch:

- if there are conflicts in `file1.txt`, I would like to use `MergeStrategy.OURS`,
- if `file2.txt` has conflicts, I would like to apply `MergeStrategy.THEIRS`.

So following are my questions:

1. how to get conflicts ahead before merging two branches?
2. how to apply multiple merge strategy on different files at same time?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question as asked, but [this looks like a job for "custom merge drivers"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/930495/1256452)

Comment: hi @sanat, were you able to find the solution for this problem, since i'm also facing same type of problem. It will be great if you can help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the JGit MergeCommand to run this, the most likely way is to run the merge with a `mergeCommand.setCommit(false)` (so that you do the dry-run), and then based on your decisions, clean the working directory and re-run the merge command with the appropriate merge strategy.

Comment: Why would you need to clean the working directory if it was a proper dry-run?