# merge strategy in .gitattributes not working

Tags: git, merge, gitattributes

I want git to never have a conflict on this file:
`test/file.txt`
when merging.
I tried the following in .gitattributes
test/file.txt merge=theirs

but I need to define the `theirs` merge strategy. I saw online that I can define the `ours` strategy by executing this:
`git config --global merge.theirs.driver true`
which sets the driver to true (bash true) which will keep the local file instead of the new one.
I want to do the opposite. How can I define the `theirs` driver to get the new copy and discard the local one when merging (after a git pull)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I define the theirs driver to get the new copy and discard the local one when merging (after a `git pull`)?

As I mentioned in "[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930495/6309)", you would need to call a script like:

```
git config merge.keepTheir.name "always keep their during merge"
git config merge.keepTheir.driver "keepTheir.sh %O %A %B"
```

With `keepTheir.sh` (put anywhere in your `PATH`)

```
cp -f $3 $2
exit 0
```

Or, as [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) suggests below [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920526/merge-strategy-in-gitattributes-not-working/27999588#comment44449601_27999588), directly:

```
git config merge.keepTheir.driver "cp -f %B %A"
```

---

Plus, as noted by [Tal Jacob - Sir Jacques](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14427765/tal-jacob-sir-jacques) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920526/merge-strategy-in-gitattributes-not-working/27999588#comment126755570_27999588):

> after you have configured the '`keepTheir`' driver in the `config` file, you should navigate to your `.gitattributes` file and add the line:
>
> ```
> test/file.txt merge=keepTheir
> ```

Comment: Why not skip the external script and define the driver as `"mv %B %A"`?

Comment: @jthill sure, that is just how I implemented it at the time 6 years ago in http://stackoverflow.com/a/930495/6309 (mainly for testing)

Comment: Note that after you have configured the 'keepTheir' driver in the config file, you should navigate to your `.gitattributes` file and add the line `test/file.txt merge=keepTheir`

Comment: @TalJacob-SirJacques Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.