# How would I set a policy of accepting the incoming file for a particular file in .git for the repository?

Tags: git, policy

We have a npm module with a `package-lock.json` and we would like to set it that we always accept the incoming changes on this file as a policy across the team.

I realise that I can set `.gitattributes` in the repo to use a merge strategy for a particular file e.g.

`package-lock.json merge=myStrategy`

... however this references a strategy which has to be setup by each user since it lives in `.git/config`.

Is there a way to have it set so that it live in source control? This way anyone working on the project will automatically adopt the practice.

I have already found a strategy for accepting incoming that should work without having to include it in the path as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27999588/199) but this is not kept in source control and requires that new users run a command before use.