# Git - How do I override a folder on master branch with a folder on a branch

Tags: git, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to merge a branch into another with override option in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922336/how-to-merge-a-branch-into-another-with-override-option-in-git)

I have some folders on a branch, I want them to just override the same folders on master.

I dont want to go through merge.. I just want a straight replace.

Any ideas how to do this in Git?
Thanks

Comment: do you mean you want to replace these folders by what's on `master`?

Comment: or you want to update `master` to be the same as your branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really quite simple:

```
git checkout master
git checkout <branch> -- <directory>
```

The first command puts you on `master`. The second takes all the diffs between `<branch>` and `master` in `<directory>` and stages them for commit.

Now just issue `git commit` as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Delete master. And commit new files to it.

Comment: I just want the specific folders on my branch to replace the ones on master.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

1. Create patch:

   git diff master mybranch path/to/folder > foo.patch
2. Checkout to master and apply it:

   patch -p1 < foo.patch