# In Git, is there a way to automatically mark all newer vesions of files in a merge conflict as correct?

Tags: git, merge, github, conflict

So I've come across a merge conflict with my repo, the older versions are all ~1 month old, is there any simple command to mark all the newer versions as correct rather than having to do it for every individual file (I'm working with ~1000 files)

Thanks

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-their) topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in the [Git merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) command, the *recursive* strategy accepts the *ours* and *theirs* options, among others. Both options resolve conflicts by overwriting the existing or incoming versions, respectively.

I don't know which version is the newer in your case, so I cannot tell you exactly which of the two options you should specify, but I guess you'll figure it out.

**Note:** As pointed out by @Mark Longair, the *ours* strategy also exists, but has a different effect than the *ours* option to the *recursive* strategy. Be careful not to confuse them.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer, I think, but you might want to emphasize that this is the `ours` and `theirs` option to the merge strategy (which are about automatically resolving conflicting hunks), and *not* the `ours` merge strategy, which discards everything from the other parent.