# Conflicts while merging - how to tell git to always use newer?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

i was just trying to merge two repositories. For some reason, the merging didn't go well and created a lot of conflicts. Most of them are due to the fact that i upadated a component in one version.

So what i would like to do is merge and wherever a conflict pops up, tell git to use the newer version.
Otherwise it would take ages to merge this.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: see [git merge -s ours, what about “their”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/173919/11343)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there's a problem with that "newer" concept: in Git, "tree objects" (which record names, sizes and hashes of blobs they reference) do not contain timestamps of those blobs.  Hence there's a logical problem of deciding which of two (or more, for octopus merge) blobs which happen to map to the same filesystem name is newer than the others.

Comment: You could imagine to lookout the timestamp of the commit this blob or tree belongs to...

Answer (score 1):

Could you not do a

```
git merge -s ours anotherbranch
```

?

Comment: hum... reading again your question, I assume it would'nt do the trick because "ours" does not have always the newest stuff, right ? :-/

Comment: What about isolating the changes concerning the new version of your component in a new dedicated branch, merging it with "ours" option, and finally merging the rest the standard way ?