# How to mark a branch as the winner in case of a git merge conflict?

Tags: git

Suppose I have two branches A and B that I want to merge in git and those two branches will generate a merge conflict. I would like to tell git something along the lines of Merge B into A and if there are conflicts take the version from B over what is in A?

Is there way to a auto declare a winner without having to do a git add on each file that conflicts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automatic pick a version when conflict happens you need to use `-X` option.

e.g.

1. `git checkout branchA`
2. `git merge -Xtheirs branchB`

If you prefer the branchA, you can use `-Xours`

Be careful not confuse -X conflict option with merge strategy, that's totally different concepts.

See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge
And [Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-their)