# Git branch diff into one new commit

Tags: git, github

So let's say I have a main branch, we'll call 'master'. I've made a branch, called 'new-feature'. I've made a ton of commits in this branch so I can go back in time, but I've done quite a bit of back and forth on while developing the feature so the commit log is pretty messy.

If I were to look at 
git diff master..new-feature
for example.

If I wanted to create just one new fresh commit on 'master' that includes all the changes in between the two branches, what's the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash new-feature
git commit
```

The commit message will start out showing the entire list of commits being
merged/squashed, but you can of course edit that to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 9):

Another option that might work better for you, would be to generate a patch file with `git diff --patch > "patch filename"` and then patch them into your master branch using `git apply "patch file name"`.

Man page for git-diff (especially "Generating patches with -p"):
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html

Man page for git-apply:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html

Comment: git apply... interesting :) Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

You can use interactive rebase for this: `git rebase --interactive`. Then just use the squash option. It only uses the updates from the commit but doesn't create the commit.

Comment: That seems like a ton of search replacing pick for squash, or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, if there were merge conflicts along the way, you'll have to do them all over again, or use something like git rerere which isn't for mortals.

Answer (score 1):

Use git rebase --interactive HEAD~(however many commits to want to squash). eg, git rebase --interactive HEAD~5. This will load your last 5 commits and bring up an editor window with the messages. Each message will have 'pick' at the beginning. Go down to the last message, change 'pick' to 'squash' and exit. A new window will open asking for a commit message. This will be the new commit message of the squash commits. Exit and it will squash all the commits into one new one.

There's an example here:
https://ariejan.net/2011/07/05/git-squash-your-latests-commits-into-one

Comment: Seems like that could create some problems seeing that I'm on a team and regularly needing to pull in changes from other team members. That, and I'd rather not count :)

Comment: If you're working on a new-feature branch I made the assumption that you're working on that branch on your own. If you're not, you/other people you're working with could probably have their own branches. Using rebase is typically a bad idea if other people have already pulled your code as it can cause problems due to the fact that you're rewritting history

Comment: So the ~5 wouldn't count commits from the master that were made I've pulled in, as long as I'm the only one committing on the branch? Does the '5' mean the last five unique to that branch, or the last five commits in total?

Comment: I believe it would be the last 5 in the log for the branch you are on. So if you have a commit which is simply 'Merge from trunk' that would be included. I would recommend following along with the article I sent, as it is probably much better at explaining it than I am.

Answer (score 0):

You could commit everything in your feature branch, then merge into master accepting 'theirs' for all changes.

Here's a Stack Overflow question with a great answer on how to do that:
[Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-their)

Comment: Hmm, does that result in only one commit representing the feature branch though?

Comment: It would if you rebase in the feature branch first (like William says above), although that's maybe unadvisable. One of the great things about source control is having the history of how you got to where you are.  I suppose that's a matter of preference though!  More on interactive rebase [here](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html).

Comment: Yeah, I'd like having the histories too, but different folks :)