# How to copy a commit from one branch to another in git without any merging?

Tags: git, copy, branch, commit

I have 2 branches a master and an experimental. A shown:

```
master-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-Y
                  \
                   -x-x-x-x
```

My experimental is quite outdated and i was hoping to update it by simply copying the last commit in the master branch (**Y**) to experimental:

```
master-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-Y
                  \
                   -x-x-x-x-Y
```

If possible, I don't want to have to do any merging I want to overwrite anything in the experimental (master is my main priority).

**Edit:**
Let me briefly explain the situation: When i try to merge commits at the tips of the master and experimental branch, I get a lot of merge conflicts! The same happens if i try to cherry-pick from the experimental onto the master! I was hoping to avoid them as i simply don't want any of the changes on the experimental! Up until now, I have been cherry-picking from master to experimental and when there are merge conflicts, I just keep changes of master branch. But after doing it many times, i was hoping that there may be some way in which i can do **something like a merge except where (i am not prompted with any merge conflicts as master changes is all i need (for all I know it wouldn't matter what was previously on the experimental branch!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I initially tried!:

```
git checkout experimental
git rebase --onto <COMMIT ID OF LAST MASTER COMMIT> experimental
```

On trying this code, I found that not only the commit at the tip of the master **but** also the entire experimental branch became a clone of the master! Yes, it is not an elegant solution and a bad usage of git!

However, as pointed out by @Johnsyweb, the optimum solution would be to do a merge of experimental and master **but,**

> with Git preferring to take the changes on master over the changes
>   on experimental

Hence doing a:

```
git checkout experimental
git merge -Xtheirs master
```

should work fine.
Although it says merge, since it only considers the changes of the experimental branch over the master one, it is more like a copy from experimental to master for all practical purposes.
(See a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364506/2110869))

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected `git rebase` to do, but that looks right to me.
It looks to me that you want to merge **all** of the changes on `master`, **since the branch-point**, into `experimental` but with Git preferring to take the changes on `master` over the changes on `experimental` where conflicts exist. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3364506/78845

Answer (score 23):

To [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) ***just*** commit `Y` from `master` onto `experimental`:

```
git checkout experimental
git cherry-pick Y
```

Alternatively:

```
git checkout experimental
git cherry-pick master
```

...Will apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the `master` branch and create a new commit in `experimental` with this change.

Comment: I am sorry but i have to merge if i follow your instructions. I was hoping to be able to do so without a merge!

Comment: @reubenjohn: Then I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "simply copying the last commit in the master branch (Y) to experimental".

Comment: @reubenjohn take a short time h to learn more about cherry pick and merge, it's two different things

Comment: @CharlesB I do know the difference between cherry-pick and merge, but unfortunately I have mislead you with a bad question! There has been a misunderstanding for which i have edited my question!