# A merged branch diverged from master yet again, what's the best way to bring changes from the merged branch back into master?

Tags: git

Branch A was merged with master, had its conflicts resolved and additional commits added.  The master branch also has addition commits.  What is the best way to merge these two branches and use branch A's changes over the master branch?

Thanks!

Comment: Google for 'git merge strategies'. There are [plenty of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3364506/877115) out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command below should do the trick - execute from master

```
git merge -s theirs A
```