# During git merge, in the case of merge conflict, how do I accept all changes from a certain branch?

Tags: git

I have two branches: `cat` and `dog`. Their histories have diverged.

I would like to merge `dog` into `cat`. In this merge, how can I accept the `dog` version of all files automatically, instead of having to resolve the merge with `git add/rm` and repeating the commit?

Likewise, how can I accept the `cat` version of all the files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git merge -s ours, what about "theirs"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-theirs)

Answer (score 4):

To accept all `dog` versions when merging `dog` into `cat`:

```
$ git checkout cat
$ git merge -s recursive -X theirs dog
```

To accept all `cat` versions when merging `dog` into `cat`:

```
$ git checkout cat
$ git merge -s recursive -X ours dog
```

`-X` specifies an option for the strategy specified by `-s`. Git merges proceed relative to the currently checked out branch, so `theirs` and `ours` are relative to the currently checked out branch.

The recursive strategy is often the default, so you might not have to use `-s`.

Documented at *git-merge(1)*.