# How do I merge two branches (not master)?

Tags: git, github, merge

I have the following branches in my github project

master
elvis
creditcard

elvis is the furthest along. I need to get all the elvis code into the creditcard branch.

From within creditcard, I tried "git merge elvis" and I get "error: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files."

Comment: what you describe here is the right approach, but from the error message it seems that you did not start with a clean working directory/index. checkout creditcard, make sure you are not within a merge operation and then run "git merge elvis".

Comment: Ok that worked, but I have about 1000 conflicts to many to fix. Is there a way to do what you said, but just force creditcard to take all elvis code without conflict? So accept all of elvis as dominant overwriting anything in creditcard instead of making a conflict?

Comment: you can use the merge strategy "theirs" http://stackoverflow.com/q/173919/2536029