# Override local changes in merge

Tags: git, git-merge

`master` -> completely messed up, my first time using `gitmergetool`

`backup` -> works fine.

How should I merge `backup` with master and make `backup` take precedence on everything, including files that exist in `master` but not in `backup` being deleted.

I've run a gun `git reset --hard <hash where everything was peachy>` and have the project back to before I attempted the merge. So how should I proceed to merge? I'm not sure where the conflicts have come from. I must have committed to the master, but I don't remember doing so.

I was thinking it would be easier to delete `master` and then rename `backup` to master, or `checkout -b master` or should I try to merge?

Comment: The following question might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-theirs

Comment: What you said at the end there, just force the move: `git checkout -B master backup`.

Answer (score 1):

So long as **you're one hundred percent sure the remote branch is perfect and the commit id is for a commit for when everything was fine**, this is a pretty sure fire way to solve all your woes:

```
git checkout backup
git reset --hard <hash where everything was peachy>
git checkout master    
git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs backup
```

Answer (score 1):

Just point master to the same place as backup:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard backup
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd just delete the `master` branch and move the `backup` branch so it's name is now `master`.

```
git branch -D master
git branch -m backup master
```