# Automatically fix a minor merge conflict

Tags: git, vagrant

When I start a merge in my vagrant botstrap I get a merge conflict:

```
==> git merge --no-ff testing/other
==> gc-gw0: Auto-merging manifests/fastd.pp
==> gc-gw0: CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in manifests/fastd.pp
==> gc-gw0: Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

This will stop the bootstrap from functioning although the conflict is really tiny.

How can I **automatically** take the version of the "other" branch for that file in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with

```
git merge --no-ff -X theirs testing/other
```

This will take the version from "other" in case of a conflict

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364506/1069083