# I merged and then committed only some of the files. How do I re-merge the others?

Tags: git, merge, commit, github-for-mac

I'm working in a feature branch. After running `git merge` from the main branch, I had two conflicts.

I manually resolved them, and then **committed only those two files, and ran `git reset --hard` to remove the other changes**.

The result - git thinks the other files were merged, while in reality, they're 100% from my feature branch.

How do I fixed this and "re-merge" with the main branch?

Comment: As you commited those conflicts you commited also your other changes from your feature branch to the main branch, I guess. So what is your goal? What should be commited at the end and what not? Thats not clear for me, when I read your question.

Comment: *"git thinks the other files were merged"* -- since the merge could not be completed automatically, it left you to solve the conflict and commit to conclude the merge and you did it as you described. Git is not guilty in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement itself is just a little off, because `git commit` writes *all* the files, not just some of them.  I'll tweak it a bit first, but feel free to skip forward to the next section. :-)

More specifically—this should help you think about Git in the future—Git writes *whatever is in the index* (which must be fully merged).  The `git merge` command builds, in the index, the result of merging two (or more but let's stick with two) commits.  If there are conflicts, Git stores the conflicted files in both the work-tree and in the index.

You can then edit the files in the work-tree, which you did.  You can use `git add` to copy the work-tree files into the index, replacing the conflicted versions with the single resolved version.<sup>1</sup>  You did that too.  You can use `git reset`, in its `git reset paths` form, to copy specific *`paths`* from the `HEAD` commit into the index, replacing whatever is currently in the index.

It's this last step that created the problem: Git had merged those other files, successfully (at least in Git's tiny little mind :-) ).  Then you told Git that it should copy the `HEAD` (current commit, pre-merge) versions of those files into the index, undoing the effect of the merge on those files.

---

<sup>1</sup>The gritty detail here is that when there is a conflict, the index winds up holding not one but *three* versions of some file.  For instance, suppose you have run `git merge other`, and `conflict.txt` has conflicting changes from base commit to `HEAD` vs base commit to `other`.  These conflicts show up in the work-tree copy, but at the same time, Git actually puts all three versions—base, `HEAD`, and `other`—into the index, under the name `conflict.txt`.  You can see them with `git show :1:conflict.txt`, `git show :2:conflict.txt`, and `git show :3:conflict.txt`, for instance.

Running `git add` tells Git to toss out the three extra index versions and store just one `:0:conflict.txt` file as the correctly-merged index version, ready for the next `git commit` command.  Git will allow another commit any time the index has only zero-numbered versions.  Whatever is in the index at that time, becomes the contents of the new commit.  (If these contents exactly match the current or `HEAD` commit, Git requires that you add the `--allow-empty` flag.  This makes it seem like the index is empty, but it's not: it's the *diff* that's empty.)

---

#### Diagramming the problem

There are several ways to go about fixing this.  To find the best and simplest, we really need to draw some diagrams.

Specifically, before you did the merge you want to re-do, you had some series of commits:

```
...--o--B--o--L   <-- mainbranch (HEAD)
         \
          o--o--R   <-- feature
```

You were on `mainbranch` (hence it was `HEAD`).  This means that `HEAD` represented commit `L` (for Local or Left-side).  You ran `git merge feature`, which identified commit `R` (for Remote or Right-side or otheR or featuRe; anyway, I generally call it `R`).  Git then computed the merge base commit `B`, which is the first place the histories of the two selected left and right commits join up.

Git then ran, in effect:

```
git diff --find-renames B L
git diff --find-renames B R
```

and combined the two diffs.  There were some conflicts, which you resolved, and some non-conflicts, which you `git reset` away to the `L` versions.  Due to the conflicts, Git made you run `git commit` yourself, and when you did, you got this:

```
...--o--B--o--L---M   <-- mainbranch (HEAD)
         \       /
          o--o--R   <-- feature
```

The new merge commit `M` has, as its contents, whatever was in the index when you ran `git commit`.

It's my guess that you did not *discover* the issue until later.  You probably did another `git checkout feature` and wrote more commits, giving:

```
...--o--B--o--L---M   <-- mainbranch
         \       /
          o--o--R--o--S   <-- feature
```

Then you went back to `mainbranch` and ran `git merge feature` again.  I can't call the new tips `L` and `R` any more, so I will stick with `M` and `S`.  Let's find the merge base of `M` and `S`, by following all the connections backwards (leftwards, including left-and-down), from both `M` and `S` simultaneously:

- It's not `M` or `S` themselves, we'd have to go back and then forward from `M`.
- It's not the `o` before `S` either.
- But `R` looks pretty good: we can go back one step from `M` to `R` by going down too; and we can go back two steps from `S` to get to `R`.

So the merge base is `R`, and Git runs `git diff` on `R M` and on `R S`.  Git then sees that `R`-to-`M` takes feature away from the `feature` code, while `R`-to-`S` adds or modifies the features.  Git tries to combine these changes, and the result is a big mess.  If the merge itself works, we get this:

```
...--o--B--o--L---M-----M2   <-- mainbranch (HEAD)
         \       /     /
          o--o--R--o--S   <-- feature
```

though it might not work well due to conflicts in the "undoing" going from `R` to `M`, vs the "doing" going from `R` to `S`.

But we might even have this, depending on what happened on the main branch:

```
...--o--B--o--L---M--N--M2   <-- mainbranch
         \       /     /
          o--o--R--o--S   <-- feature
```

(in which case the merge base was still `R`, but the first diff was to compare `R` to `N`).

#### Option 1: remove `M` entirely

If we *don't* have commit `N` at all, *and* if it's safe to "remove" commit `M` entirely, we can just do that, using `git reset`.  We can `git checkout mainbranch` (to attach `HEAD` to it), `git reset --hard` to commit `L`, and have this:

```
...--o--B--o--L   <-- mainbranch (HEAD)
         \
          o--o--R--o--S   <-- feature
```

Then `git merge feature` will run diff on `B L` and a second diff on `B S`, and try to combine the diffs.  You'll have mostly the same merge conflicts as `B L` vs `B R`, plus perhaps some more.

You can resolve them the same way (repeating earlier work).  Or you can save the identity of commit `M` and extract the resolutions from `M`.  Although we have erased `M` from the drawing, it's actually still in the repository.  It's just *hidden*; it will really go away later, if you don't do anything else, in about a month.  Since `M` is still in there, we can extract files from it:

```
git show <hash-id>:<path>
```

We can even attach a name to `M` before we do the `git reset`.  For instance, using a tag name:

```
git tag temp-save-merge <hash-id>
```

we can then:

```
git show temp-save-merge:<path>
```

to get the saved files.  Once we're done, we can just `git tag -d temp-save-merge` to drop the special name for commit `M` (which will, as before, let Git remove it automatically some time after 30 days, now that there are no names by which we can see/reach it).

#### Option 2: keep `M`

If commit `M` has been pushed elsewhere, though, and/or if commit `N` exists and/or has been pushed, it may not be such a great idea to attempt to *remove* `M` from existence.  We may succeed in removing it from *our* repository, but it might *come back* from another repository later.  We'd have to force-push to make it go away from any central repository, and convince everyone else who uses that repository to discard *their* copy of `M`.  If we need `N` we'd have to bring it back as well.

Instead, we'd probably like to reconstruct the files we wish we had not `git reset`, and bring those changes in atop `N`.  I'll leave commit `N` in the drawings from here on; if `N` doesn't actually exist, we're just building atop `M`, and the result is all the same anyway.

First, let's get rid of `M2` (which is unsuccessful at best and presumably has not been pushed anywhere) by running `git merge --abort` if we haven't actually *made* `M2` yet, or by `git reset --hard` if we have, so that we have a clean index and work-tree and have this graph:

```
...--o--B--o--L---M--N    <-- mainbranch
         \       /
          o--o--R--o--S   <-- feature
```

Next, let's make a *new* branch pointing to commit `L`:

```
git checkout -b temp-merge <hash-of-L>
```

which gives us this diagram:

```
                ----M--N   <-- mainbranch
               /   /
...--o--B--o--L  <-- temp-merge (HEAD)
         \       /
          o--o--R--o--S   <-- feature
```

We'll stop drawing `mainbranch` for a bit since it's getting all messy.  We can now run:

```
git merge feature
```

to repeat the same merge we did incorrectly earlier.  This will get us a "new and improved" merge, although it will stop with the same conflicts as before.  We'll get the correctly-merged files out of `M`, add them, and commit:

```
git show <hash-of-M>:<path1> > <path1>
git show <hash-of-M>:<path2> > <path2>
git add <path1> <path2>
git diff --cached   # inspect carefully
git commit
```

Now we have this:

```
...--o--B--o--L---M2  <-- temp-merge (HEAD)
         \       /
          o--o--R--o--S   <-- feature
```

Now let's add a copy of `N`, using `git cherry-pick mainbranch`, and attempt to draw it all:

```
                ----M--N   <-- mainbranch
               /   /
...--o--B--o--L---/-M2--N2   <-- temp-merge (HEAD)
         \       //
          o--o---R--o--S   <-- feature
```

This final commit `N2` is what we would *like* to have in branch `mainbranch`.  The reason we are doing all this hairy stuff, though, is to preserve the existing hash IDs `M` and `N`, so what we want now is something Git doesn't quite offer: a "theirs strategy" merge.  (See [Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173919/1256452))

But we can get what we need anyway, using one of the methods in that other answer.  Here's the most obvious one, which assumes you are sitting at the top level of your work-tree:

```
git checkout mainbranch
git merge -s ours --no-commit temp-merge
git rm -rf .
git checkout temp-merge -- .
git commit
```

The `git merge` step starts the merge, but with `--no-commit`, never finishes it.  We use `--ours` just to make it go fast: this means "keep the contents of `N`", which is quite wrong.  Then we remove everything!  The index is now truly empty.

Now we use the real trick: we re-fill the index *from the `N2` commit*.  The `git checkout temp-merge -- .` command replaces everything we have with the contents of the commit to which the name `temp-merge` points, i.e., `N2`.  This happens in both index and work-tree, so now we are all set to commit the final merge result.  When we do we get this graph:

```
                ----M--N---M3   <-- mainbranch (HEAD)
               /   /      /
...--o--B--o--L---/-M2--N2   <-- temp-merge
         \       //
          o--o---R--o--S   <-- feature
```

where the *contents*—the tree—for commit `M3` is exactly the same as that for `N2`, which is the corrected tree.

We can now delete the branch name `temp-merge`.  The history is full of our double merge, so the graph is always messy to draw.  That's because we chose Option 2, in which we *don't* rewrite history to erase our earlier mistake.  The mistake is preserved for all time, but this also means that we're only adding *new* commits (`M3` and its side chain that used to be called `temp-merge`), so other people using clones of this repository can work in their normal fashion.

#### Summary

If you *can* use Option 1 (rewrite history, pretend the bad merge never happened), you probably should.

You can even use a sort of hybrid: start with the temporary merge branch method, make commit `M2`, and cherry-pick `N` to `N2` if `N` exists.  But then, instead of merging this with `mainbranch`, *rename* the old `mainbranch` and rename the temporary merge to `mainbranch`, giving:

```
                ----M--N   <-- mistake
               /   /
...--o--B--o--L---/-M2--N2   <-- mainbranch (HEAD)
         \       //
          o--o---R--o--S   <-- feature
```

You may have to force-push the renamed temporary branch, and this makes headaches for other users if there are any, but if we then delete the `mistake` branch later and draw our graph, we get:

```
...--o--B--o--L--M2--N2   <-- mainbranch (HEAD)
         \      /
          o--o-R--o--S   <-- feature
```

which is quite normal looking.  (And, note that we can now merge `S` atop `N2` in the usual way.)  It does mean we have rewritten history, but we did it in a sort of easy-ish way: we re-did the merge of `L` and `R`, grabbing the correctly-merged files out of commit `M`, then we tossed commit `M` and `N` aside in favor of `M2` and `N2`.  This is effectively the same as Option 1, except that we keep the mistake branch around until we're done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the super informative answer! Just a clarification, though - I merged FROM the main branch, not TO the main branch :)

Comment: @Dor: ah. You said "running `git merge` from the main branch" and I assumed that meant you did `git checkout mainbranch; git merge ...` (i.e., run `git merge`, from / while-on the main branch). Anyway the *source tree* of a merge does not depend on the "direction" of the merge, except for options like `-Xours` and `-Xtheirs`. It's which branch gets the final merge commit, and which parent is the `--first-parent` one, that depends on the "direction" (i.e., the current branch during the merge).