# How to use THEIRS git merge strategy in android studio?

Tags: git, merge, merge-strategy

We developed in some branches with lot of commits in them and because we where not sure about the probable bugs. After a lot of changes we decide to migrate whole project into master branch without any changes so we select master branch but there is no THEIRS git merge strategy could be found. Using git with CLI doesn't make any difference too. What's the problem?

Comment: I guess nobody will know without looking at your actual repository...

Comment: I agree with @TimothyTruckle and I also think this is not an Android studio nor Android question. Its a git question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/173919/1256452 but note that some answers are about `-X theirs` and what it does, and other answers are why `-s theirs` does not exist and how to fake it.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I thought this is because of android studio git GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in an untidy way. I copy all of files/directories from my latest commit and go to the master branch and delete old files then replace new files. Finally made a commit and merge latest branch into master in regular way. So I didn't waste any more time to merge conflicts.