# Git / Gitlab Flow Workflow

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow

We have the following branches in our project:

- master
- preproduction
- production

We use branches like feature/myfeature-123 to develop new function. If they are done, we merge those into the master.
After a while, when enough features are done and successfully merged into master, we deploy our project to preproduction. For this, we need to merge the latest changes into the preproduction branch.

**Note: Nothing was changed in the preproduction branch in the meantime**

And here is our problem: 
We face many merge-conflicts. Then i thought, okay. Lets fix it manually.
I did the following:

1. Checkout preproduction
2. (Just to be safe) Pull the latest changes in this branch (There were none)
3. Create a new branch from the current branch i am in. Name: deployment-april2019
4. Switched to this new branch
5. `git pull origin master` to get the current state from `master` into this branch.

As stated above, we face a lot of merge conflicts. Since we changed nothing in the preproduction branch, i wanted to accept all changes that were done in the master branch. This should fix all conflicts.

This worked, **BUT** in the master branch we deleted several files / lines that were also in the preproduction branch. I would have expected, that those deleted files / deleted lines would also be applied to the preproduction branch. But this was not the case. They stayed in the preproduction branch. Any ideas what to do, to solve this?

I am not the biggest expert in this. I have a general understanding of Git, but i am still afraid of breaking things by executing the wrong commands. I thought if `rebase` could help here, but i dont know.

I am very thankful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Before the merge, is `preproduction` behind `master` or diverged? You can check with `git branch --contain preproduction`, if `master is listed, `preproduction` is behind.

Comment: The deleted files are still part of the branch? Or are they just still hanging around in the folder?

Comment: @padawin: yes ... preproduction is 321 behind and 9 ahead. I think those 9 ahead, come from earlier deployments to preproduction, where new commits / merge requests where applied to preproduction, but not to master.

Comment: @kowsky: I dont understand the question right i guess. But i try to explain it more clear: 

In master and preproduction there is a file called UserService. This was deleted now in master, since we dont need it anymore. When i pulled the master into my deployment-april-2019 branch, the file was still there. In other words, i did not get deleted.

Comment: @MaxSchindler if you are sure that master is newer and preprod is behind, my suggestion should work for your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, that master is the source of truth and is kind of a `fast-forward` (!). 
You could just merge while accepting from Master. 
This then can be done by a job f.e. in Jenkins/Travis/CI.

Add the -X option to theirs. For example:

```
git fetch --all  --prune
git checkout preproduction
git merge -X theirs origin master
```

Everything will merge in the desired way.

[Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours)

The advantage with this approach is, that you still preserve the commit history.

Answer (score 0):

It might be good to bring back `preproduction` up to track with `master`. You can do the following:

```
git log --oneline master..preproduction
```

To list the 9 commits in preproduction only.

Then, reset `preproduction` at the state of `master`:

```
git checkout preproduction
git reset --hard master
```

Finally, add back to preproduction any of the 9 commits listed above that you are interested in with:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

You will then have to force push back `preproduction` as it will have diverged from the origin.

That will bring it up to track with `master`. Ideally though, you will want no commit in `preproduction` only, to it can be easy to push it with a latest master in the future.