# Remove everything from the master branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two branches - develop and master. 
I worked constantly on the dev branch and the master is completely unnecessary code, quite different than on dev branch.

how to transfer everything from dev to master in such a way that nothing is left of the old master ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options:

First - if you want to destroy every trace of the history of `master` you can just set `master` to `dev` -- similar to the answers of @Krantisinh and @ashishmohite:

```
git branch -f master dev
```

If other people have build upon the old state of `master` they are screwed. So talk to them before you do that.

Second - you want to keep the history of master but swap out the contents: Then you are doing a special merge like this:

```
git checkout master

# git merge -s theirs simulation
git merge -s ours dev
git branch temp_THEIRS 
git reset --hard dev
git reset --soft temp_THEIRS
git commit --amend
git branch -D temp_THEIRS
```

This merges `dev` into `master` but takes *all* content from `dev`  -- no conflicts - no questions asked. This comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56368650/947357.

Third - (as per comment) if you want to throw away `master` (as in "First") but also start `master` without any history:

```
git checkout --orphan new-master
git commit -m "start from scratch again"
git branch --force -M new-master master
```

After that `dev` and `master` do not share any history.

Comment: And what I want to create a new, empty branch and push them on the master, removing the master content?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the master branch. And then create a new master from dev branch.

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
git checkout develop
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

If you want to push your new master branch to remote, then you can use force push option, it will overwrite the old master from the remote.

```
git push origin -f master
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete master branch if it's not locked
and then checkout the master branch from develop

```
git checkout dev
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

Comment: I thought about it but would not it cause any problems later? e.g if someone wants to do a push on the master?