# How to tell git to accept all current changes

Tags: git

So I was just trying to upload my code to git, I don't know what I did but somehow i'm in a bit of pickle.

Because there are so many conflicts in almost all of my files.

I don't want to resolve each conflict manually by going through each file because there are hundreds of files and there are multiple conflicts in each file.

So how do I tell git to accept all current changes but not the incoming changes or vice versa? Thanks

Comment: If you undo the merge (`git reset <hashOfYourLastCommit>`), and you're ready to push... `git push -f` will forcefully push your changes. This will overwrite history though (and probably has some bad consequences if hundreds of files have changed), so be careful.

Comment: You have to deal with the conflicts. And you have to do it now (you cannot deal with them during a later commit). Unless, of course, you did something blatantly wrong. Ignoring conflicts and saying "I'm right, they are wrong" without looking does not get you anywhere.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```sh
git checkout --theirs .
git add .
```

or

```sh
git checkout --ours .
git add .
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when rebasing a branch on top of another branch.

Comment: What is --theirs and what is --ours?

Comment: theirs: incoming changes | ours: current changes

Answer (score 8):

```
git checkout --ours [filename]
git add [filename]
```

https://dev.to/willamesoares/git-ours-or-theirs-part1-agh

To initiate the merge with this intent, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours).

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, then you could:

1. Select all the files having conflicts under **Git** sidebar icon
2. Right click and then choose **Accept All Current** or **Accept All Incoming**.
3. Save all the automatically changed files.
4. Stage Changes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> So how do I tell git to accept all current changes but not the incoming changes or vice versa? Thanks

From the docs:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

---

You have to use merge strategies,

> **`git checkout  --ours / --theirs`**
>
> When checking out paths from the index, check out stage (ours) or (theirs) for **unmerged paths**.

---

#### Short post:

http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html

---

#### Note by [@j69](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6868543/j6t)

Be warned: `checkout --ours` and `checkout --theirs` erases **all** of the not-chosen edits in the file, even the ones outside the conflicts.

Comment: I tried the `git checkout  --ours / --theirs` but the output is `fatal: '--ours/--theirs' cannot be used with switching branches`

Comment: Sounds like you're using a branch name instead of a file name.

Comment: @Danz Tim use the dot `git checkout --theirs .` and then `git add .`