# GITLAB: How to push ENTIRE branch to another one

Tags: git, gitlab, git-reset

My goal is pretty simple to explain, but yet I could not find any way to do this.
Let's say I have 3 branches. A, B and C

```
A -------.
          \--------.----------- B
                     \
                      .-------------- C
```

I simply want to push the entire branch "C" to the branch "B".Let me explain: I don't want to keep any stuff that I did in B after I created C from it. I simply want B to have the exact same code which have the branch C.

How can I safely do that ?

There's more than 10 000 files of difference between the two of them so manually is not an option.

I tried several stuff including a git merge with "theirs" strategy but I still had a lot of conflict somehow.

Comment: Is branch B shared with anyone else?

Comment: @RomainValeri I'm currently working alone on this repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the number of potentially conflicting files or the differences in code, either of these three commands

```
# if you don't need to checkout the branch immediately
git branch -f B C

# if you DO want to checkout the branch immediately
git checkout -B B C

# if you branch B is ALREADY checked out
git reset --hard C
```

would make `B` point at the same commit than `C`, making them exactly identical, code and history. No conflicts resolution, no merges, it's instantaneous.

**Note that this is considered a rewrite of `B`'s recent history, so this is not to use if you're sharing branch `B` with anyone.**

It'll also dereference any commit made on `B` after `C` was branched off it, so if you have any doubt, beforehand make a backup of `B` with

```
git branch backup-B B
```

---

Lastly... you've forgotten to make a backup and have a regret? `git reflog` will list previous positions of `HEAD`, you'll find `B` there, recover it with `git reset --hard <old position hash>` or put a handle on it for inspection/reuse with `git branch recovered-B <old position hash>`

Answer (score 4):

Checkout B then reset HEAD

```
git checkout B
git reset --hard C
```

Comment: Best solution **if** you need to also checkout the branch (one-liner variant `git checkout -B B C`).

Answer (score 3):

There is no `theirs` strategy.  There's a `-X theirs` *option*, but that is not a strategy. Git calls it a "strategy option", which is a bad name: it sounds like an option that provides a strategy, but in fact, it's an option *to* some *other* strategy, the one from the `-s` option, which defaults to `-s recursive` here.  I call `-X` an "eXtended option" to help avoid confusing it with the `-s` option.

For a description of *why* there is no `-s theirs`, even though there was at one time, see [this answer by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741538/1256452).

The various reset methods (`git checkout -B`, `git reset --hard`, and the like) in the other answers here are usually the way to go.  However, if you want to produce the *effect* of a `-s theirs` strategy easily, see [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16526138/1256452) to [Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173919/1256452)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to discard all changes unique to `B` then delete it:

```
git branch -d B
```

Checkout `C` and create a new `B` from it:

```
git checkout C
git branch B
```

`B` is now exactly the same as `C`.

Comment: If B hasn't been push you'd need to use `-D` instead of `-d`