# git merge issues - force merge

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have two branches in git.

Branch dev and my feature branch 1300.

Branch 1300 is a complete refactoring of branch dev. Now I'm finished with 1300 and want to merge it into the dev branch.

How can I do a merge force 1300 into dev.

When I do a normal merge and accept theirs in intellij (theris is 1300) the files I deleted in 1300 are still in dev.

Any hints for a force merge?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use the `--ours` option, but it would be better to just clean up the merge conflicts/issues by hand, based on your understanding.

Comment: ours kees the stuff from dev? I want to keep the stuff from 1300.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "force merge" in Git.  Luckily, that's not what you want anyway.  What you want is `git merge -s theirs`.  Unluckily, that doesn't exist.  Luckily, there are ways to fake it.  See also [Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173919/1256452)  I could close this as a duplicate, but instead I'm going to write up a long-form answer.

#### Git commits, including merge commits

The word *merge* has two or more meanings, depending on whether you're using it as a verb, *to merge*, or an adjective-or-noun: *a merge commit* (adjective) or *a merge* (the adjective becomes a noun, as [adjectives are wont to do in English: this is called nominalization](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/440166/180540)).  The noun version, *a merge*, simply is there in your repository, as a commit, just like any other commit, except that instead of the usual single parent, it has two.<sup>1</sup>

Remember that a commit, in Git, is composed of two things: a *snapshot*—a saved set of files—and some *metadata:* information about the commit, such as who made it, when, and why.  In the metadata, Git stores the hash ID(s) of some earlier commit(s).  These are the *parents* of the commit in question.  Most ordinary commits have a single parent hash ID; what makes a commit a *merge* commit is that it has two parents, instead of the usual one.  But it has only one *snapshot*.  That snapshot is the merge result.

I find pictures to be very helpful here.  First, let's draw a picture of a simple string of commits—a "branch", if you will—in Git:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain of commits.  Since `H` is a commit, it has both data—a snapshot—and metadata.  The snapshot holds all of the files as of the form they had when you, or whoever, made the commit.  The metadata for `H` contains the actual raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  We say that `H` *points to* `G`.

`G`, of course, is also a commit: a snapshot (of the files as of then) and metadata.  This metadata points back to an even-earlier commit `F`.  `F`, like `G`, has a snapshot and metadata, so it points on back.

What all this means is that as long as we can find the *last* commit, we can find *all* the commits in the chain.  So that's what a Git branch name does: it lets us find the *last* commit in the chain.  It just holds the hash ID of that commit.  Whatever hash ID the *name* holds, that's the *last* commit *in that chain*.  So this might look like:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

Here, branch name `feature` points to commit `J`, which points back to commit `I`, which points back to commit `H`, which points back to `G`, and so on.  The fact that there's another name, `main`, that points to `H` doesn't stop *all* the commits I just listed from being on *both branches*.  The fact that `main` points to `H`, however, *does* stop commits `I` and `J` from being on that branch.  The commits up through and including `H` are on both branches, while the last two are only on `feature`.

We can add and remove any names we like at any time.  There are just a few constraints.  For instance, the names must meet certain tests: `main` and `feature` are fine, but `hello..world` is not because double-dots are forbidden.  The names also need to point to actual commits.<sup>2</sup>  I won't cover everything, but you should get the idea: we can create and destroy any names within certain (reasonable) limits.  So we can add a name `dev` to the picture above, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- dev, main
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

If we now `git checkout dev` or `git switch dev`, so that this becomes the *current name*—we'll get commit `H` out as the *current commit* in this process—and then make a few new commits, we will need to redraw the graph a bit.  Here I've put `feature` up top and `dev` down below:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             K--L   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

This drawing shows us that we have two commits (`I-J`) that are *only* on `feature` and two that are *only* on `dev`.  The `(HEAD)` notation shows that we are currently using the name `dev`, and therefore using commit `L`, which is one of the ones *only* on `dev`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, any commit with two *or more* parents is a merge commit, but two suffices, and having two is typical.

<sup>2</sup>There's no technical reason for this, and Git is acquiring a feature in which this constraint will be relaxed for certain names, but it's currently always required for all names, and will still be required for *branch* names.

---

#### The mechanics of merge-as-a-verb

When you choose to make a merge commit—usually, by running `git merge`—you select the two (or, per footnote 1, more) commits that you are tying together.  One of the two is the *current commit*, which you select *before* running `git merge`, usually with `git checkout branch` or `git switch branch`.  The other is the commit that you name on the command line.  Hence we might run:

```
git checkout dev
git merge feature
```

for instance.<sup>3</sup>  Git will then go off and find a *third* commit on its own.  This third commit is the *merge base*, and the merge base provides the starting point for the action of merging: the *to merge* process, or merge as a verb.

The problem you have is that if your picture looks like this:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

—I've erased the name `main` to keep it from cluttering up the picture; it doesn't really matter if it's there or not—the `git merge` action, the *merge as a verb* process, will work by:

- locating the best commit that's on *both* branches, which in this case is obviously commit `H`;
- comparing the snapshot in `H` to the one in `L` (`dev`) to see what *we* changed;
- comparing the snapshot in `H` to the one in `J` (`feature`) to see what *they* changed;
- *combine* those changes and apply the combined changes to the snapshot in `H`; and
- make its final merge result by using those *combined* changes.

The result will look like this:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- dev (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L
```

Note how the branch *name* `dev` now points to the new commit, `M`, as a result of doing this merge process.

---

<sup>3</sup>You can add `git merge --no-ff` to prevent Git from doing a fast-forward *instead* of a merge.  I suppose one could view this as forcing a merge—but it's still not what you want. :-)

---

#### There is an `ours` strategy

The *strategy* thing that [Tim Biegeleisen refers to in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65824828/git-merge-issues-force-merge#comment116383056_65824828) is how Git actually implements the merge-as-a-verb process.  When you run `git merge`, this does a bunch of preliminary tests and handles various command line options.  One of the allowed options is `-s`, and `-s` takes a *strategy* argument.

The strategies that Git has built in, out of the box, are:

- `-s recursive`: this is the usual default one.  It does the combining we talked about above.
- `-s resolve`: this is a variant of `-s recursive`; it too does this combining.  We don't need to go into the technical difference between them here because your issue is that you'd like to avoid the combining.
- `-s octopus`: this is a kind of special purpose algorithm for merging more than two commits.  It isn't the answer you want here.
- `-s ours`: this is another special purpose algorithm.  It's *almost* the one you want!

What the `ours` strategy does is simple: in order to make the new snapshot, it *completely ignores* the other commit(s) you specify with your `git merge` command.  It then says that the new snapshot should exactly match the current commit.  So if we're on `dev` and we run `git merge feature`, we get:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- dev (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L
```

**This looks exactly the same as before, until we look at the *snapshot* in commit `M`.**  Before, the *snapshot* in `M` was the result of *combining work on two branches* and applying the combined changes to the merge base snapshot from `H`.  Now, the *snapshot* in `M` is exactly the same as the snapshot in commit `L`.

This is *oh so close* but **still not what you want, because what you said you want is to make `M` as usual, but use the snapshot from commit `J`.**  If Git had a way to do that out-of-the-box, it would be spelled `-s theirs`.  Apparently Git once *did* have `-s theirs` (this must have been pre-Git-1.6), but it does not have `-s theirs` now.

**There are a bunch of ways to fake it.**  See the linked answer (should be a duplicate) for these various ways.  **Be sure that you really do want to fake it.**  You will end up with a merge commit `M` whose snapshot matches whichever "side"'s files you choose.

As several answers there note, be wary of `-X ours` and `-X theirs`, which have a very different meaning.  These options—I like to call them *eXtended options*, to make it clear that they're not the *strategy* (`-s`) option—are passed *to* the strategy to do with as it wishes.  The default recursive/resolve code uses this to resolve *conflicts* automatically.  It does not *completely ignore* one side's changes.  Instead, it takes either side's changes, but when those changes have conflicts, *resolves* the conflicts using one side's changes, throwing out the other's for that particular diff-hunk only.