# Git merge? - completely ignore one branch changes

Tags: git, git-merge

I got a classic situation - master and multiple branches. I need to merge changes (many changes through multiple commits) into *master*, but I want to ignore any changes that were made in *master* itself. I want *master* to be a clone of my branch.

I know that I could just *checkout* every file from branch into *master* and commit changes, but that won't make graph pretty :)

How can I achieve that? Solving merge-conflits is not enough, because there are still some changes that were auto-merged. Do I have to remove them manually or is there some `git merge --magic` option that could help me?

**ADD:**
I'd like files to be exact copy between branch and *master* (not commit history), but I'd like to have all that squished to single commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to realize that Git stores *snapshots* (which Git calls the *tree* of a commit).  There are no *changes* in any commit, just a snapshot and some metadata.  If you see changes, that's an illusion brought about by taking *two* commits and *comparing* them.  Think about [an old style movie film](https://ssec.si.edu/stemvisions-blog/what-physics-behind-watching-movie): each frame of the film holds a snapshot image, frozen in time, and we only *see* movement because we look at 24 carefully-sequenced frames every second.

What this means is that you can construct a commit "by hand" at any time if you like.  If you want the snapshot of commit `a123456` to be the next snapshot on the *current branch*, you simply make a new commit whose parent is the current commit, but whose tree is from commit `a123456`:

```
git commit-tree -m "insert your message here" -p HEAD -p a123456 a123456^{tree}
```

or similar.  The two `-p` arguments here make this a merge commit, so that this is the result of the missing `-s theirs` merge strategy.  This new commit—Git prints its hash ID to stdout; you must grab it from there—is not yet on any branch, so you now need to update the current branch name, using `git merge --ff-only` or `git update-ref`.

See [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16526138/1256452) to [Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173919/1256452) (note that the question itself is now a bit confused due to December 2008 edit to the original October 2008 question, and some answers are about `-X theirs`, which is different).

Comment: nice - I hadn't seen this before. It has the bonus of not actually affecting the topic branch.

Comment: ~~@torek that's a great solution, but after I did `git commit-tree` as you presented, `git merge --ff-only` returns "Already up to date." And calling `git update-ref` return help-page. I also don't see any changes in `git log` after all doing all of that.~~ **EDIT** I didn't notice that `git commit-tree` returned new commit number, my mistake, sorry for ping :) Everything is great now :)

Comment: @mrozo: added a note about that. You should click through to jthill's answer though.

Answer (score 16):

The answer depends on whether you care about preserving the history of the base branch. If you use a `git reset --hard`, you'll lose the history of `master` that diverged from the feature branches.

If you want to maintain history, a better trick would be to do it as two merges, with the first merge using the `-s ours` merge strategy.

```bash
git checkout feature
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only feature
```

The first merge, `git merge -s ours master` will create a merge commit with no file-changes on the `feature`branch. The parents of this merge commit are `feature` and `master`, but the code is no different from the head of `feature`.

The second merge will fast-forward `master` to that merge commit. The end result will be two branches with the exact same code and preserved histories. The code will be exactly the same as `feature` prior to the two merges.

There isn't a single option or command to perform this operation. `-Xtheirs` is not truly a merge strategy, it's just an option for the default merge strategy that tells it how to resolve conflicts.

`git merge -s ours` exists specifically for the operation of merging the history of obsolete branches and throwing away the changes. There is no `-s theirs` strategy.

The trick here is that you want to throw away the changes on `master`, but still keep the branch afterward. Normally, you would just delete the obsolete branch after doing an `-s ours` merge.

Comment: You saved my butt royally with this! Thank you so much. Your description was clear, and solution perfect! I just wanted to drop you a big thank you @TonyArra